# How to use specific repo tool version

Tags: repo

I installed repo on my system, but why can't I see its version using 'repo --version' until 'repo init' is run!
Also to suppress repo init to connect to android repo git, I have to pass --repo-url. Is it possible to suppress this behaviour, because it forces me to use repo version from --repo-url and not the one I installed??

Answer (score 1):

In order to ensure you use the newest version (or for compatibility), when you run `repo init`, repo tool will download a new version of repo in your .repo/repo. So by default, `repo --version` is designed to check the version in your .repo/repo.

If you want to avoid using --repo-url, you can download repo source and add the directory of repo source to your PATH environment variable.